# Ubuntu 19.04 Freezes on Desktop

Tags: freeze, 19.04

My Laptop: HP Pavilion 14-cm0xxx

Everytime i boot Ubuntu or linux in general on it, it lasts about 30 seconds then freezes completely and never recovers. I opened top and it shows that ld-2.23.so consumes all my cpu usage then freezes but on another computer the same ld task hits 100% the other computer functions fine.

Is there a way I can stop this freeze on my Laptop?

Answer (score 1):

How much RAM does your computer have? Ubuntu desktop is a very demanding OS, and if you think your device can't take it, you should try a more lightweight flavour of Ubuntu, such as [MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/), [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) or [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/). All of these operating systems are based on Ubuntu, and have all the same packages and features as Ubuntu, so you will not be missing anything.